# What happens when a UI screen is 'loaded'?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml

I have been working on Qt/qml based UIs.

I used something like 'dynamic on requirement loading' of screens. (using a loader element)

Advantage: All screens need not load at startup, improves systems startup time.

Disadvantage : When ever a screen has to be loaded later, it takes time, and decrease in user responsiveness at that moment.

My question is, what is actually 'loaded' into the memory when I say, load a UI screen ?

I mean if its C++ code, I would understand it like some dynamic objects are being created. I cant visualize it in terms of UI screens ? Is it like the images I have used in making that UI are loaded into memory for different operations ?

Adding to the earlier question, what happens when I 'unload' a screen ?

Is the CPU requirement same for loading and unloading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very good and detailed explanation what exactly going on when declarative engine loading a qml file:

http://www.kdab.com/qml-engine-internals-part-1-qml-file-loading/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link sergk. Just one more doubt, do all these steps happen whenever we run the qml code ? or its like normal C++ executable where you can compile once and run it any number of times without needing a recompilation ?

Comment: Loading instantiating and binding runs just once, when you load a QML file. Binded expressions (generated javascript bytecode) runs every time a connected signal emitted.

Answer (score 1):

When loading an QML object with loader the program actually creates an object in memory of each element that you have in your QML file (calls constructor for that elements class). You can think of any QML element in your file as a corresponding c++ class.
When you unload these views the destructor of each element would be called. So the answer to the last question would be that CPU requirements for loading and unloading would be different.